# invariant violation: requirenativecomponent: "rncamera" was not found in the uimanager

Tags: react-native, camera

In react native I want to add a barcode scanner and take a picture on my app  but I am running  in to the following error:

> invariant violation: requirenativecomponent: "rncamera" was not found
>   in the uimanager.

When barcode component view opens.

```
react-native-camera 3.3.0
react-native sdk-32 (expo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with react-native-camera, rebuild(react-native run-android) fixed the problem. I have noticed that similar issues with other libs as well. I think linking sometimes doesn't properly take affect with just reloading

Answer (score 1):

you will most likely have to eject to native code out of expo because any third party package that asks you to run the command "react-native link" as part of the setup process is strictly to be used with pure react native app. hope that helps